# grub rescue: "failure reading sector 0x802 from hd0"

Tags: debian, grub

I lost power on my debian jessie laptop and now, when I boot it, I get:

```
failure reading sector 0x802 from hd0
grub rescue>
```

I tried:

```
ls
(hd0),(hd0,msdos1),(hd0,msdos2),(hd0,msdos5)
```

then, I tried:

```
set root=(hd0,msdos1)
set prefix=(hd0,msdos01)/grub
insmod normal
```

and i get:

```
failure reading sector 0x802 from hd0
```

I am terrified now ( I have quite a lot of office stuff on my laptop, and I am unsure how to proceed...)

I would REALLy appreciate any help or directions to try to try to get back into my system

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Booting a live media and running an error correction tool is my first and only suggestion.

Comment: After you boot into a live media OS try to reinstall grub.

Comment: did someone solve this problem?

Comment: there is no "solution", there is an error on the disk.  Could be just a little corruption, or a big problem, as @CelticWarrior said above, just boot a rescue media, and try to fix it :(

Answer (score -1):

change from UEFI mode  to legacy mode in bios settings , then it will work for sure

Comment: Why would this fix a failure to read a disk sector?